# Need some explanation for null move pruning in case of zugzwang

Tags: algorithm, chess, alpha-beta-pruning

[image]

In this position white in zugzwang position. He tries null move pruning with beta value of INF, since this is the first move.

A call into the function following null move will look something like this

```
-AlphaBeta( -beta, -beta + 1, depth-4, pos, FALSE)
```

So the value returned by the black piece is 0, since any move will result in a stalemate. So the value of score is always less than the value of beta, which implies we cant do pruning for this tree and we have to search the entire game tree from the viewpoint of black. Then what is the disadvantage of null move pruning over here when we are finally getting the correct score ?